# "!Missing $ inserted." when using svn $Id$ keyword substitution

Tags: errors, packages, revision-control

I'd like to to surface subversion revision numbers for use in the contents of my document.  `svninfo` and `svn` packages rely on [svn keyword substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html) to accomplish this, but I get this error when I try it:

> Error line 6 ! Missing $ inserted.

Here's the entire document that causes this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svninfo}

\begin{document}
\svnInfo $Id: doc.tex 8 2013-04-11 19:37:31Z User Name $ %<= Id keyword substituted by svn  

\end{document}
```

The usual suggested remedies for this error are to escape the $ like this: `\$`  However, no combination of escaped and non-escaped `$` characters both avoids this error and has useful results.

How do I avoid this error *and* surface svn revision numbers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The username may not have a space. this runs without error

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svninfo}

\begin{document}
\svnInfo $Id: doc.tex 8 2013-04-11 19:37:31Z UserName $ %<= Id keyword substituted by svn  

\end{document}
```

---

Since Windows user name allows spaces, you can let svnInfo allow them as well. this seems to work:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svninfo}

\makeatletter
\def\@svnInfoCrackAndEat #1 #2 #3 #4 #5 #6 $ {\@svnEndRead
  \@svnInfoCrackString #2 #3 #4 #5 {#6} $ %
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\svnInfo $Id: doc.tex 8 2013-04-11 19:37:31Z User Name $ %<= Id keyword substituted by svn  

[\svnInfoOwner]

\end{document}
```

Comment: @alx9r it may be worth asking the package maintainer to update the package with this patch to support spaces

Comment: Thanks very much.  That indeed works.  I have sent an email linking here to the package maintainer.

Answer (score 8):

You have a space in the user name:

```
\svnInfo $Id: doc.tex 8 2013-04-11 19:37:31Z UserName $
```

should work

Comment: That's it.  In case it helps someone else, the user name, complete with space, was lifted by ToroiseSVN from the underlying Windows 7 account.

Comment: @alx9r ooh it would be easy enough to modify `\svnInfo` to allow a space sounds like that would be useful as svn is going to keep putting the space back?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes that would be very useful.  All of the other workarounds I've found so far are pretty messy.

Comment: @alx9r: `User~Name` should work

Comment: @Herbert It might not be obvious, but that doesn't help since all of the characters between the two `$` are overwritten automatically by SVN when you commit the file.

Comment: @alx9r: sure. I meant that your subversion should write it this way.